# How to run a script on multiple sheets, Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I would like to run on specific tabs in my Google worksheet, but not necessarily all of the tabs.  I tried doing two differently named scripts, but only the last one that was saved will run.  How can I code this script to run on specific tabs?  This is my beginning script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Proposal');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('B:B')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'Hide') 
        s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

I tried modifying like this, using suggestions from another question posted, but it did not work.

```
function onEdit() {
  var tabs = [
        'Proposal',
        'Materials List - All',
        'Materials List - Shingles',
        'Materials List - Access',
        'Work Order'
  ];

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

    s.getRange('B:B')
      .getValues()
      .forEach( function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] == 'Hide') 
          s.hideRows(i + 1);
      });
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to do this properly?  How could I do this on all the tabs if I decided that was easier?

Thank you!

Comment: You added a variable `sheet`, but didn't use it (your code still uses `s`despite `s` being undefined now).

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch! How would I change it so that it runs?  I tried changing all the singular s to ss but that did not work.

Comment: Of course that will not work. If you read and understand your code, you will see that the variable `ss` refers to an object of class [`Spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), not an object of class [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). You may find it very helpful to complete JavaScript tutorials (internet search, there are many).

Comment: Yes, I am a novice at this and just started to learn how to code.  Once I get this project finished I can continue the online tutorials.  Been doing lessons through Code Academy unless you have a better suggestion?  I'm open to finding great resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways. Using 'exclude' or 'only'.

**exclude** means, do not do it if current sheet is one of these.

**only** means, do it only if current sheets is one of these.

Use below code and enable any one option then try. To enable, add respective sheet names to `excludes` or `only` array and uncomment lines by taking out `//`. It'll work only on current sheet, not all sheets in the spreadsheets.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // use only one of these 2 options

  // add sheets names to exclude, example ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
  // to exclude these sheets enable these 2 lines below by uncommenting
  // var excludes = [];
  // if (excludes.indexOf(s.getName()) != -1) return;

  // add sheet names to work on only these sheets, as above
  // to work on only these sheets enable these 2 lines below by uncommenting
  // var only = [];
  // if (only.indexOf(s.getName()) == -1) return;

  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
  s.getRange('B:B')
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function(r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'Hide') s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var only = [
    'Proposal',
    'Materials List - All',
    'Materials List - Shingles',
    'Materials List - Access',
    'Work Order'
  ];
  only.forEach(function(name) {
    var s = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
    s.getRange('B:B')
      .getValues()
      .forEach(function(r, i) {
        if (r[0] == 'Hide') s.hideRows(i + 1);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This works except that it skips one of the tabs and it's not consistent as to which tab it skips.  For example, one time it will skip the "proposal" tab and another it will skip the "work order" tab.  This is what the updated script looks like (see next comment):

Comment: function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var only = [        'Proposal',
        'Materials List - All',
        'Materials List - Shingles',
        'Materials List - Access',
        'Work Order'
 ];
 if (only.indexOf(s.getName()) == -1) return;

  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
  s.getRange('B:B')
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function(r, i) {
      if (r[0] == 'Hide') s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}

Sorry!... don't know how to format the comment to show the script properly.

Comment: Will the code search through all the tabs mentioned and do the function on all those specific tabs, or only the active tab if the name of the tab matches?  I'd like it to perform the function on all the tabs mentioned, not just the one that is active.

Comment: From your code, it'll work only if current sheet is 1 of those 5 sheets. And it'll work on current sheet only. Sheet names in code have to be exactly the same as in spreadsheet. So, what do you need now ? Put code inside ` characters to show as code.

Comment: edited code. now it'll work on those listed sheets. copy the new code and try! hiding rows could take some time if there are may rows in sheets as code hides rows one by one.

Comment: Perfect!  Worked like a charm.  Thank you so much!!