# How to apply Google Apps Script to multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to apply the following code to multiple tabs in the same Google Sheet. Defining different Tabs in the first var, or applying multiple .gs files in the same project each with a different var did not succeed.

```
var naamWerkbladKasboek = "Kasboek"; 
var naamWerkbladOpties = "Opties";
var eersteKolomMetInput = 2; 
var tweedeKolomMetInput = 3; 
var derdeKolomMetInput = 4; 

var werkblad = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(naamWerkbladKasboek);
var werkbladOpties = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(naamWerkbladOpties);
var Opties = werkbladOpties.getRange(2, 1, werkbladOpties.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues();


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  var werkbladName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  
  if(werkbladName === naamWerkbladKasboek && column === eersteKolomMetInput && row > 1){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val, row);
  } else if(werkbladName === naamWerkbladKasboek && column === tweedeKolomMetInput && row > 1){ 
    applySecondLevelValidation(val, row);
  }
} 

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val, row){
  
  if(val === ""){
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
      var gefilterdeOpties = Opties.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = gefilterdeOpties.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
      var cell = werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}


function applySecondLevelValidation(val, row){
  
  if(val === ""){
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      var waardeEersteKolomMetInput = werkblad.getRange(row, eersteKolomMetInput).getValue();
      var gefilterdeOpties = Opties.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === waardeEersteKolomMetInput && o[1] === val });
      var listToApply = gefilterdeOpties.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
      var cell = werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule)

}
```

I have tried working with the only and exclude tags as indicated here: [How to run a script on multiple sheets, Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224103/how-to-run-a-script-on-multiple-sheets-google-sheets) and also tried working with an array as indicated here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115076/how-to-run-script-on-multiple-google-sheet-tabs but both to no avail. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

As an example I can show how I tried to work with the only tag

```
//**EDIT**
var only = [
"Kasboek1",
"Kasboek2",
"Kasboek3"
];
var naamWerkbladOpties = "Opties";
var eersteKolomMetInput = 2; 
var tweedeKolomMetInput = 3; 
var derdeKolomMetInput = 4; 

var werkblad = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(only);
var werkbladOpties = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(naamWerkbladOpties);
var Opties = werkbladOpties.getRange(2, 1, werkbladOpties.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues();


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  var werkbladName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  
  if(werkbladName === only && column === eersteKolomMetInput && row > 1){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val, row);
  } else if(werkbladName === only && column === tweedeKolomMetInput && row > 1){ 
    applySecondLevelValidation(val, row);
  }
} 

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val, row){
  
  if(val === ""){
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
      var gefilterdeOpties = Opties.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var listToApply = gefilterdeOpties.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
      var cell = werkblad.getRange(row, tweedeKolomMetInput);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}


function applySecondLevelValidation(val, row){
  
  if(val === ""){
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput).clearContent();
      var waardeEersteKolomMetInput = werkblad.getRange(row, eersteKolomMetInput).getValue();
      var gefilterdeOpties = Opties.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === waardeEersteKolomMetInput && o[1] === val });
      var listToApply = gefilterdeOpties.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
      var cell = werkblad.getRange(row, derdeKolomMetInput);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule)

}
```

Comment: @Marios I don't think this is relevant to OP's situation.

Comment: @user14339468 what do you mean by `both to no avail.`? What is happening and what is different to what you want?

Comment: Thank you Mario, but this does not work. I also have functions below the onEdit which use the variables defined at the beginning of the document. If I put this variables below the different onEdit versions, nothing happens. In addition, if I change the var to "Kasboek1" && "Kasboek2" it only works on the last one I typed in.

Comment: [Edit] to show the  script that you *have tried working with the only and exclude tags as indicated here: How to run a script on multiple sheets, Google Sheets*

Comment: Thanks, TheMaster. I included the only tag. This cannot work, because it seems to be used like an attribute to a function in the example while I use it as a variable that is called. Should I include it prior to onEdit?

Comment: Consider taking a basic arrays or JavaScript course. You cannot use `only` like that. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `onEdit` you check if the name of the current sheet contains "Kasboek"

```
function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var activeSheet = activeCell.getSheet();
  
  if(activeSheet.getName().includes("Kasboek")){
    KasboekModification(activeCell);
  } else {
    //code here if changes need to be made on other sheets
  }
}
```

After that you have your `function KasboekModification(cell){}` function where you can do the magic of your current sheet.

Comment: I've checked this with OP outside of SO. If sheet name should be limited down more strictly I'd agree with your solution.

Comment: Sorry Marios, gave this code a try and it works for my purpose so I was very happy. I am sure you have a good point with saying that activeSheet.getName() returns a single value. I will look it up, but am not that experienced with JavaScript so it might take me some time to figure it out. Is there anything else I can do for you? I was very happy with your help and do not want to act against the rules of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*A simple solution would be to return out of the `onEdit(e)` if the sheet that has been edited is not one of the pre-defined ones to edit.*

#### Code Sample:

To do with *only*:

```js
var only = ["Sheet1Name", "Sheet2Name", "Sheet3Name"]; // add sheet names as desired

function onEdit(e) {
  if (!(only.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
    return;
  }
  // put the rest of your onEdit function here
}
```

or with *exclude*:

```js
var exclude = ["Sheet4Name", "Sheet5Name", "Sheet6Name"]; // add sheet names as desired

function onEdit(e) {
  if (exclude.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
    return;
  }
  // put the rest of your onEdit function here
}
```

---

#### Example for your use case:

```js
var only = ["Kasboek", "Kasboek2", "Kasboek3"];

function onEdit(e) {
  if (!(only.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
    return;
  }

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();

  if (row <= 1) return;

  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  var eersteKolomMetInput = 2; 
  var tweedeKolomMetInput = 3; 
  var derdeKolomMetInput = 4;
  
  if (column === eersteKolomMetInput) {
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val, row);
  } 
  else if (column === tweedeKolomMetInput) {
    applySecondLevelValidation(val, row);
  }
} 

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val, row) {
  // ...
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val, row) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Many, many thanks for your help. Although I am still struggling with this code. My original code included a reference to a specific tab to which it was applicable. When just adding more tab-names the 'onEdit(e)' function does function on al these tabs. With including these (already selected) tabs, I do not get any further. Excluding tabs I do not want to fucntion to apply to with 'exclude' does not work either. Should I make my onEdit function applicable to the entire sheet with all its tabs and just exclude a the ones I want or include the ones I want?

Comment: @user14339468 The `onEdit(e)` will run regardless of which tab is edited. You can either use `exclude` or  `only` but you don't need both, the two above samples are effectively equivalent. After the if statement, you will need to make sure you have your conditional code to check if `row > 1` or otherwise, but without the name check again. I'll update my answer with an expanded example for your use case.

Comment: Rafa, you are an amazing person. Thank you so much! This is very kind of you! I will check this out in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I am working on the same thing. I have a sheet that I have which runs a script to duplicate it (with it's protections). I excluded all the backend sheets, except the sheet that it pulls the options from. But it didn't work. Secondly, I want it only to work in the sheet I am working on currently, i.e., if I update a cell in a different worksheet it should not affect this one (unless it is the options Sheet). When I duplicate a sheet it should still work. which is why the OG function checked the main worksheet name with the active worksheet name. I have typed my code in below.

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 7, file "multipledatavalidation")

line 7; **if (exclude.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
return;**

It should be noted I have another script running on my sheet as well. One that allows me to duplicate the sheet with its lock in place. I want to be able to run this code on all copies that I make of the original sheet.
here is a [link to a shared, editable, version of my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGuFBRcB5Ig093r9-_LU6XEqllwHm1hHiCQ-TDini74/edit?usp=sharing).

```
     var optionsWsName = "Backend-Prices";
      var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
      var exclude = ["BackendImportedData", "donotedit", "BackendDataSort", "09/20_DS7"]; // add sheet names as desired
    
// function to update each time the file is Edited 

function onEdit(e){
      if (exclude.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
        return;
      }
      
      var Options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1, 5).getValues();
      var activeCell = e.range;
      var val = activeCell.getValue();
      var r = activeCell.getRow();
    
      if (r <= 8) return;
    
      var c = activeCell.getColumn();
      var FirstLevelColumn = 1;
      var SecondLevelColumn = 2; 
      var ThirdLevelColumn = 3; 
      var FourthLevelColumn = 4;
      
      
      if(c === FirstLevelColumn){
        applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r);
      } else if(c === SecondLevelColumn){ 
        applySecondLevelValidation(val, r);
      } else if(c === ThirdLevelColumn){ 
        applyThirdLevelValidation(val, r);
      }
    
}//end onEdit
    
    
    
    // function for second level of data validation to work correctly
    
function applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r){
      
      if(val === ""){
          ws.getRange(r, SecondLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, SecondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        } else {
          ws.getRange(r, SecondLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, SecondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          var filteredOptions = Options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
          var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
          var cell = ws.getRange(r, SecondLevelColumn);
          applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
        }

}
    
    // function for third level of data validation to work correctly
    
function applySecondLevelValidation(val, r){
      
      if(val === ""){
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        } else {
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          var firstlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, FirstLevelColumn).getValue();
          var filteredOptions = Options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstlevelColValue && o[1] === val });
          var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
          var cell = ws.getRange(r, ThirdLevelColumn);
          applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
        }
        
}
    
    
    // function for fourth level of data validation to work correctly
    
    function applyThirdLevelValidation(val, r){
      
      if(val === ""){
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        } else {
          ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          var firstlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, FirstLevelColumn).getValue();
          var secondlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, SecondLevelColumn).getValue();
          var filteredOptions = Options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstlevelColValue && o[1] === secondlevelColValue && o[2] === val });
          var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[3] });
          var cell = ws.getRange(r, FourthLevelColumn);
          applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
        }

}

    
function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
      
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
 .newDataValidation()
 .requireValueInList(list)
 .setAllowInvalid(false)
 .build();
      
 cell.setDataValidation(rule)
    
    }
```