# How can I apply Google Apps Script to multiple sheets (dependent drop downs)?

Tags: google-apps-script

I get this message when I tried to run the script that I got from [@Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062070/how-to-apply-google-apps-script-to-multiple-sheets):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' Line: 11 File: Code.gs

Line:11 was

```
if (!(only.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
   return;
}
```

Here is the whole code:

```
var optionsWsName = "드롭다운 확인";
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1, 4).getValues();
var only = ["2021 1월", "2021 2월", "2021 3월"];
var firstLevelColumn = 3;
var secondLevelColumn = 4; 
var thirdLevelColumn = 5; 
var fourthLevelColumn = 6;

function onEdit(e) {
   if (!(only.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName())) {
   return;
   }

   var activeCell = e.range;
   var val = activeCell.getValue();
   var row = activeCell.getRow();

   if (row <= 1) return;

   var column = activeCell.getColumn();

   if(c === firstLevelColumn){
     applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r);
   } else if(c === secondLevelColumn){ 
     applySecondLevelValidation(val, r);
   } else if(c === thirdLevelColumn){ 
     applyThirdLevelValidation(val, r);
   }

} 


function applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r){
      
      if(val === ""){
          ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        } else {
          ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
          var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
          var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
          applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
        }

}
    
    
function applySecondLevelValidation(val, r){
      
      if(val === ""){
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        } else {
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
          var firstlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
          var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstlevelColValue && o[1] === val });
          var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
          var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);
          applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
        }
        
}
    
    
    
function applyThirdLevelValidation(val, r){
      
      if(val === ""){
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        } else {
          ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn).clearContent();
          var firstlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
          var secondlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).getValue();
          var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstlevelColValue && o[1] === secondlevelColValue && o[2] === val });
          var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[3] });
          var cell = ws.getRange(r, fourthLevelColumn);
          applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
        }

}



function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
      
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
 .newDataValidation()
 .requireValueInList(list)
 .setAllowInvalid(false)
 .build();
      
 cell.setDataValidation(rule)
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a missing closing parenthesis. This should remove the syntax error:

```
if (!(only.includes(e.range.getSheet().getName()))) {
   return;
   }
```

**Tip:**

The Apps Script IDE would tell you if there are missing closing brackets/parenthesis if you place the cursor before or after the symbol. Also, the IDE would also mark the next bracket with a red underline meaning that the previous statement has not been completely closed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But now I'm receiving this error message, could you help me figure out why the range the undefined in my script for the same line 11?

TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ code.gs:11

Comment: You should not run ````onEdit(e)```` function directly from Google Apps Script. It will automatically run on every edit you do on the spreadsheet.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers