# How to get all sheets by openById while stand-alone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a stand-alone script to action for another spreadsheet. It's working for the first sheet only, but it's not working for all sheets.

```js
function doSomething(){
    var ssID = "123abc";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);

    //var sheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets(); I also
    //   tried it, but it gave an error.
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var range = sheet.getRangeList(['A3:A','D3:D']);
    range.setFontFamily("Arial");
    // The rest. Do something
}
```

I need an example to work all sheets and need work all except individual sheets.

Comment: `var sheets = ss.getSheets()` it will get you the array `sheets`. Now you can get any sheet as an element of the array: `var sheet1 = sheets[0]; var sheet2 = sheets[1]; // ...etc`

Comment: But how to get all sheets with a single var?

Comment: You can get all the sheets with a single var this way: `var sheets = ss.getSheets();`

Comment: Well, but it's giving error on getRangeList:  'TypeError: sheets.getRangeList is not a function'

Comment: Of course. An array has no method `getRangeList()`. You can take a sheet from the array first. Something like this: `sheets[0].getRangeList();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a script on multiple sheets, Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224103/how-to-run-a-script-on-multiple-sheets-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through all the sheets and set the font for the range it can be done this way:

```
function doSomething(){
  var ssID = "123abc";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheets_to_skip = ['aaa', 'bbb']; // names of the sheets you want to skip

  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (!sheets_to_skip.includes(sheet.getName())) {
      var range = sheet.getRangeList(['A3:A','D3:D']);
      range.setFontFamily("Arial");
    }
  })
}
```